# Getting error while restoring backup file on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a compatibility issue when I try to restore the database backup which is taken on SQL Server 2014. But I have SQL Server 2012. Please help me to solve this problem.

Below is the error message

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to Generate a `script file` and execute it in required server.
While generating Select Your Server version `Sql2012`

Comment: what do you mean by this `While generating Select Your Server version Sql2012`

Comment: I mean While generating Script file, Select `Script for Server Version` as `Sql Server 2012` @TheGameiswar

Comment: how can you specify option as sqlserver 2012, can you elaborate

Comment: @TheGameiswar, In SSMS, Tasks-> Generate Scripts -> Selet Database -> Choose Option Script for Server Version .

Comment: Great, Thanks never knew about this option

Answer (score 1):

You cannot downgrade a backup. It is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Restoring backup taken on higher versions and restoring it to lower versions is not possible. you need to script out tables and run them on 2012, you also should account for any 2014 features which might not run on 2012..

below are the steps

right click database ->tasks->generate scripts

[image]

select entire database

[image]

in next step,click advanced and change below properties

[image]

finally save

[image]

you also can use export data like below

[image]